# How to check if an access token is expired in Laravel Passport?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

i'm trying to check if an access token is expired using Laravel Passport.

I have a protected route with auth:api middleware

```php
Route::middleware('auth:api')->post('/test', [TestController::class, 'index']);
```

If a token is expired or invalid i get a 401 response

```json
{"message": "unauthenticated"}
```

But if the token has expired i want to send a different response. For example

```json
{"message": "token expired"}
```